# My middleware is returning Not Found instead of redirecting 'away'

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

This is my middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    $uuid = $request->route('link');

    $link = Link::where('uuid', '=', $uuid->first());
    if ($link === null) {
        return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');

    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But instead of redirecting to google.com, I get the 'Not Found' page.
Where is the problem?

Comment: if you are using route model binding that could be throwing the not found

Comment: Try this: $link = Link::where('uuid', $uuid)->first();

Comment: I am indeed using a route group function

Comment: @lagbox is there anything I can do to make the redirect I want?

Comment: its not the middleware causing the "not found"

Comment: What do you need in order to know what’s causing the error?

Comment: Route group function is not the same as model binding. Are you using model binding in the controller function?

Comment: Yes, I do. @mrhn

Comment: What are you trying to achieve everytime you access this model it should redirect?

Comment: I want to redirect someone when they enter my domain with a string after the '/' that's not a value inside my database